# How to develop an after serverror trigger in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, error-logging

I'm trying to log all the errors in my database into a table. So as user sys i wrote the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE servererror_log (
    error_datetime  TIMESTAMP,
    error_user      VARCHAR2(30),
    db_name         VARCHAR2(9),
    error_stack     VARCHAR2(2000),
    captured_sql    VARCHAR2(1000));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_server_errors
AFTER SERVERERROR
ON DATABASE
DECLARE
 captured_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT q.sql_text
  INTO captured_sql
  FROM gv$sql q, gv$sql_cursor c, gv$session s
  WHERE s.audsid = audsid
  AND s.prev_sql_addr = q.address
  AND q.address = c.parent_handle;

  INSERT INTO servererror_log
  (error_datetime, error_user, db_name,
   error_stack, captured_sql)
  VALUES
  (systimestamp, sys.login_user, sys.database_name,
  dbms_utility.format_error_stack, captured_sql);
END log_server_errors;
```

But when i force an error like trying to select from a non-existing table it doesn´t log the error in the table.

Is there any way to check that the trigger fires at all? Also, I tried creating a test table to insert there but it doesn't work either, even if a define the trigger as an autonomous transaction and commit inside the trigger.

Thanks, 
Joaquin

Answer (score 3):

Do not query v$sql; get the statement using ora_sql_txt.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_server_errors
AFTER SERVERERROR
ON DATABASE
DECLARE
sql_text ora_name_list_t;
stmt clob;
n number;
BEGIN
  n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
  if n > 1000 then n:= 1000; end if ;
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
     stmt := stmt || sql_text(i);
   END LOOP;

   INSERT INTO servererror_log
   (error_datetime, error_user, db_name,
    error_stack, captured_sql)
   VALUES
   (systimestamp, sys.login_user, sys.database_name,
   dbms_utility.format_error_stack, stmt);
   commit;
 END log_server_errors;
 /
```

Then:

```
SQL> select * from c;
```

This produces:

```
select * from c
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

That can now be queried:

```
select * from servererror_log;
```

To produce:

```
ERROR_DATETIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR_USER                     DB_NAME
------------------------------ ---------
ERROR_STACK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAPTURED_SQL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-FEB-09 02.55.35.591259 PM
SYS                            TS.WORLD
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
select * from c
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Also I've tried this same approach before with no results. It seems like the trigger isn't firing. Any other ideas? Do you know how can I check if a trigger has been fired? Something like a view with a LAST_FIRED_TIME column or something like that. 
Thanks Joaquin

Comment: Could be the insert. The problem is, if the trigger fails, its hard to catch. I'd either use UTL_FILE or a separate procedure with autonomous transaction. See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492705/is-there-any-way-to-log-all-failed-sql-statements-in-oracle-10g

Answer (score 1):

To see if the trigger is firing, add one or more lines to it like this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Got this far' );
```

In SQLPlus, SET SERVEROUTPUT ON then execute a command to generate an error.  You should get output like this:

```
dev> select * from aldfjh;
select * from aldfjh
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Got this far
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of your trigger and/or the existence of other triggers with:

```
select trigger_name, status
from all_triggers
where triggering_event like 'ERROR%'
```

This should result into:

```
TRIGGER_NAME        STATUS
------------        -------
LOG_SERVER_ERRORS   ENABLED
```

If trigger is not enabled or another trigger fails, it probably will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Save this as `ORA-00942.sql`:

```
-- Drop trigger and ignore errors (e.g., not exists).
DECLARE
    existential_crisis EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( existential_crisis, -4080 );
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER TRG_CATCH_ERRORS /*+ IF EXISTS */';
    EXCEPTION WHEN existential_crisis THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ignoring non-existence.');
END;
/

-- Drop table and ignore errors (e.g., not exists).
DECLARE
    existential_crisis EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( existential_crisis, -942 );
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TBL_ERROR_LOG /*+ IF EXISTS */';
    EXCEPTION WHEN existential_crisis THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ignoring non-existence.');
END;
/

-- Create the table (will not exist due to drop statement).
CREATE TABLE TBL_ERROR_LOG (
    occurred      timestamp,
    account       varchar2(32),
    database_name varchar2(32),
    stack         clob,
    query         clob
);

-- Create the trigger to log the errors.
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CATCH_ERRORS AFTER servererror ON database
DECLARE
    sql_text   ora_name_list_t;
    n          number;
    query_     clob;
BEGIN
    n := ora_sql_txt( sql_text );

    IF n > 1000 THEN n := 1000; END IF;

    FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
        query_ := query_ || sql_text( i );
    END LOOP;

    INSERT INTO TBL_ERROR_LOG
        (occurred, account, database_name, stack, query)
    VALUES
        (systimestamp, sys.login_user, sys.database_name,
     dbms_utility.format_error_stack, query_);
END;
/
```

Run using sqlplus:

```
SQL> @ORA-00942.sql
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Table created.

Trigger created.
```

Test it:

```sql
select * from blargh;
select * from TBL_ERROR_LOG;
```

Output:

```
  2017-10-20 15:15:25.061   SCHEMA  XE  "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"   select * from blargh
```