# How can I do an on commit trigger with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Oracle 11gR2, triggers

I have a table Student (id, name)

I have this triggers :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER TR_STUDENT 
AFTER INSERT ON STUDENT

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('end of transaction');

END;
```

And I want to insert data in the table :

```
INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('djjjkt'); 
INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('doadkjf'); 
INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('djjodjfijt'); 
INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('dkdakmfakmf')
COMMIT;
```

I have the following results :

```
1 line inserted
end of transaction

1 line inserted
end of transaction

1 line inserted
end of transaction

1 line inserted
end of transaction

COMMIT
```

And I'd like to have

```
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
end of transaction

COMMIT
```

Could you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('end of transaction') after each insert? or do you need to end the transaction after each insert. Does it throw any errors..

Comment: If you could explain *why* you need to do anything when a commit is issued, perhaps we can help by providing options to solve your problem. As it stands, it's not clear why you would want to display the message "end of transaction".

Comment: Put simply - no, you can't fire a trigger ON COMMIT. The potential trigger points are: You can create triggers to be fired on any of the following:
  DML statements (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE)
  DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP)
  Database operations (SERVERERROR, LOGON, LOGOFF, STARTUP, SHUTDOWN)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the missing ON COMMIT trigger is to use a materialized view (MV) with ON COMMIT REFRESH and add a trigger to this MV, as described in
[How to define a trigger ON COMMIT in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098771/how-to-define-a-trigger-on-commit-in-oracle).
The MV can be on the base table (Student) itself or it can be on an auxiliary table, where one row is inserted and immediately removed by a base table AFTER STATEMENT trigger.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to understand the difference between row level and statement level triggers.

Check this link [TRIGGERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536516/how-to-develop-an-after-serverror-trigger-in-oracle?rq=1) for statement level and row level triggers.

If you need only the different formatted output like below

```
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
1 line inserted
 end of transaction
```

put your `dbms_output.put_line` at the end of all isert statement.

To use commit or rollback in your trigger use [pragma](http://psoug.org/reference/autonomous_tx.html).