# Using ODBC Trace or Oracle Trace to find cause of error?

Tags: oracle, odbc, trace

I have a third party Windows service which controls/monitors equipment and updates an Oracle database.  Their services occasionally report an error about a row/column in the database being "bad" but do not give the underlying database error, and their services need to be restarted and everything is fine.  The current suspicion is that something from our applications/services which read/write to those same tables/rows are interfering - i.e. some kind of blocking/locking.  I suspect that there is some sort of leak in their system since it happens about once a week, but our systems never need any re-starting like this.

I attempted to have the DBA run a trace run in Oracle (10g), but this managed to make our apps unable to access the Oracle database.  Our systems access Oracle in .NET, either using the Oracle ODP client or Microsoft client (older programs) and on this same server (either web apps or services) or from other control workstations.  The third-party services connects to Oracle via ODBC on this server.  I also attempted to run a ODBC trace (since that would only be activity from the third-party service), but didn't get anything in the trace file at all.

So I'm trying to find a way to either get ODBC tracing working or what I need to look out for so that the Oracle trace doesn't kill my server.

I'm looking for the undserlying error which Oracle is returning to the thrid-party service so I can tell if we are interfering with their access to the data in some way.

Comment: Ouch! If Oracle trace stops you from using your DB then isn't that the place to start? You can prove you have a problem your end whereas you don't actually know whether the third party's error is their fault or "yours".

Comment: what third party doesn't give the underlying ORA error?  This seems extremely suspect (either poorly written or its in some log somewhere)

Comment: Maybe one of these answers will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492705/is-there-any-way-to-log-all-failed-sql-statements-in-oracle-10g

Comment: Did your DBA do a server or client-side trace?  If it was a server-side trace, try a client-side one instead by  adding  [TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sqlnet.ora) in the sqlnet.ora file on the server making the ODBC calls and see if anything appears in _ORACLE_HOME_ \network\trace\.  Also, is anything appearing in the database's alert log?

Comment: For ODBC tracing of this sort you'll need to enable machine-wide tracing in the ODBC Administrator's "Tracing" tab. You'll need to enable this before the third-party stuff starts up or you'll get nothing in the output log. Make sure your log file path points to a disk with lots of free space as the trace will chew up a bunch of it.

Answer (score 0):

If a block in the database is corrupted "Bad" this should show up in the alert logs as an ORA-01578 error.  I would search the archive log for the ORA- error and then compare that with the time stamp on the client error being reported.  This is making the assumption of the definition of "Bad".  It would be better to have the exact error messages posted.

Blanket tracing in the database is a tricky thing as it will tend to affect the performance of your entire application. And leaving it on for an entire week may not be feasible.  I have also found in one case (cant remember the exact circumstance) where turning on tracing fixed the error.

One method I have used in the past is to add the sql statement to alter the session and turn on sqltrace.  This is predicated on the ability to modify the code in some way.  Depending on the application this may or may not be possible.

Another method would be to work with the DBA to identify the session and turn on sql trace for that session.  Also if you can identify the offending sql statements and parameter values you may be able to replicate the problem outside the service.

I have found most ORM's avoid passing the ORA- error back.  However it is typically logged in the application server layer with the associated ORM error.

I have used these method and variations of these method to trouble shoot errors in the application. I hope this is useful.